# SDL Web 8.1.0 with hot fix CD_8.1.0.1418 is not working with si4t Search

Tags: web8, si4t, solr

I am using SDL Web 8.1.0 with hot fix CD_8.1.0.1418 for Si4t solr search. I followed steps mentioned in [Search Module](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v5&lang=en-US&docid=GUID-814D5C17-9320-4BC4-B50B-6CC007D79C32&query=%2B%22Solr%20Search%22#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-E241F065-1CDC-439B-BDF0-689F6C63BE32.xml&docid=GUID-E241F065-1CDC-439B-BDF0-689F6C63BE32&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E241F065-1CDC-439B-BDF0-689F6C63BE32). When I am publishing content, I am getting  following exception:-

2016-09-14 20:13:12,468 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-9592-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to configure filesystem storage provider with storageId defaultdb, no path was specified. Unable to configure filesystem storage provider with storageId defaultdb, no path was specified
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:219) [cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:107) [cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:71) [cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.lambda$pipelineRunnable$2(TransactionManager.java:345) [cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to configure filesystem storage provider with storageId defaultdb, no path was specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.SpringContentDeliveryKernel.ensureInitialised(SpringContentDeliveryKernel.java:38) ~[cd_core-8.1.0-1227.jar:8.1.0-1227]
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.registerKernel(KernelFactory.java:40) ~[cd_core-8.1.0-1227.jar:8.1.0-1227]
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.getKernel(KernelFactory.java:27) ~[cd_core-8.1.0-1227.jar:8.1.0-1227]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getComponent(StorageManagerFactory.java:70) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getStorageManager(StorageManagerFactory.java:49) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:176) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:122) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:58) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1228]
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:91) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:142) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:115) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:108) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:76) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:74) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:207) [cd_deployer-8.1.0-1229.jar:8.1.0-1229]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to configure filesystem storage provider with storageId defaultdb, no path was specified
    at com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory.configure(FSDAOFactory.java:60) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1228]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:127) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1228]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:71) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1228]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.initialize(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:54) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.0-1228.jar:8.1.0-1228]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]

It is throwing exception for file storage but I have not mentioned in my cd_storage_conf.xml. See below my cd_storage_conf.xml:-

```
    <Configuration Version="8.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Global>
    <Storages>
        <StorageBindings>
            <Bundle src="SearchDAOBundle.xml"/>
        </StorageBindings> 
        <storage
          Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL"
            Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120"/>
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                <Property Name="user" Value="*********" />
                <Property Name="password" Value="*******" />
            </DataSource>
            <Indexer Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer"DefaultCoreUrl="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" Mode="http" DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt"/>
        </storage>
   </Storages>
   </Global>
   <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
    <!-- <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" /> -->
<!-- <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/> -->
</ItemTypes>
<License Location="D:\Web 8.1.1\Web 8 Developer License\cd_licenses.xml"/>
<ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://192.168.20.205:8082/discovery.svc"
                  ConnectionTimeout="40000"
                  CacheEnabled="true"
                  CacheExpirationDuration="600"
                  ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10"
                  ClientId="registration"
                  ClientSecret="*******">
    <Roles>
        <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://192.168.20.205:8084/httpupload">
            <Property Name="undo.enabled" Value="false"/>
            <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
        </Role>
    </Roles>
</ConfigRepository>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue.Can you please tell me how did the problem got resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You may have to uninstall and reinstall your Deployer Service after applying the hotfix.

It is also recommended to upgrade to 8.1 CU 1 (aka 8.1.1) instead of trying to apply hotfixes on 8.1.0.

Comment: Hi @rick-pannekoek first thanks for quick response. I Uninstall and reinstall Deployer service but it did not help. I am getting same exception which i was getting earlier.

Comment: Hi @rick-pannekoek when i tried deployer (Only deployer) of Web 8.1.1 I got following error which i was getting in 8.1.0 without hot fix. See error :-                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you reinstall the Deployer Service after deploying SI4T?

Comment: I have reinstalled Deployer service but exception does not go out. what else can be reason? When i used web 8.1.1 then the jar version of cd_datalayer-8.1.0-x inside the deployer/standlone/service/deployer-service does not change with web8.1.0. I am not sure that it is the reason or not?